# How to set up individual and organization memberships with fees based on custom field?

Tags: civimember

I'm working on a new CiviCRM setup where the client has two types of memberships: individual and organization.

For an **individual** membership, the user can be one of 8 types that fall into one of two categories: full member and associate member. The fee is based on the individual's income level (separate drop-down selection field), with unique fees for first time users.

For an **organizational** membership, their is only one type of membership. The fee is based on the size of the organization (5 different levels in a separate drop-down selection field). The org needs to have an individual member in order to join.

What is the best way to set these two up in CiviCRM with Membership Types and Price Sets?